# azure ad b2c Prevent Password reuse

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to send the password as part of output claims but it never comes up. I tried to create a new extension variable and do a tranformation copy claim but that didnt work either.

- I would like to hash the password and store it in external system to work around the issue of not repeating password as thats a security requirement.

If I try to add

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
```

as part of

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
```

and the whole login screen stops working.

Please let me know if I am missing something and also on how to hash the password to send it to an external RestAPI Technical profile

REST API that I used

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST API</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-ValidatePassword">
          <DisplayName>Encrypt the password and validate it against previous passwords</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://test********</Item>
            <!--<Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://your-azfunc-api.azurewebsites.net/api/EncryptClaims</Item>-->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passEncrypted" PartnerClaimType="passEncrypted"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isPasswordUsed" PartnerClaimType="isPasswordUsed"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: Please vote if you need this feature. The feedback ticket is https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34839976-aadb2c-password-history-policy

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/65):

"AAD and AAD B2C do not maintain a password history. Currently therefore you can only prevent the last password from being used.

We don’t recommend using external systems to maintain a password history."

Have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-reset-not-last-password).

You could perhaps copy the password to an extension attribute and output that but then you are exposing the password.

A better way is to use a REST API that saves the password so everything is done server-side.

Comment: I would need to pass the password as part of the REST API, the problem is I cant send the password as part of Inputclaim, Azure strips it and I dont receive that information in the rest API. I update the original request with the TechnicalProfile

Comment: @Vijay - It won't strip it if you define the `DataType` as a string. But, then you have to use Javascript to convert it to a password input on the input. It also will not strip it if you use it as part of a Validation Technical Profile.

Comment: I also tried copy claim to copy into an extension attribute and i dont think that works as well, as I tried to use jwt.ms to display the outputclaim and it wasnt there.

Comment: I will try those Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this by copying password claim when it is available. You just need to remember that copying password to another claim makes it vulnerable to logging etc. You need to do it with proper care.

To have a copied password value you need another claim:

```
<ClaimType Id="pwd">
   <DisplayName>Password</DisplayName>
   <DataType>string</DataType>
   <AdminHelpText>password</AdminHelpText>
   <UserHelpText>password</UserHelpText>
   <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

then, a claim transformation:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyPass" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
   <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
   </InputClaims>
   <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="pwd" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
   </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

and that claim transformation added to a proper technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="eSTS-NonInteractive">
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyPass" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="pwd" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

You should be able to use pwd claim value (containing actual password) for whatever you need then.